# Get text from outer span without text of inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I want to extract some text from an HTML element in Selenium and Javascript.

```
<span class="myAttribute"> 
  <b>SomeValueToIgnore</b> 
  <span class="ignoreWhatsInside">
    <em>ignore_that</em>
  </span>
  GiveMeJustThat_NothingElse
</span>
```

How can I extract the text 'GiveMeJustThat_NothingElse' from the span element in Javascript / Selenium?
Unfortunately I cannot put the text 'GiveMe...' into an own tag, because that would break other tests.

Comment: Why cannot use xpath?

Comment: This post might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479422/how-do-i-get-the-text-of-a-nested-element-in-html-for-automation-using-selenium . Thanks

Comment: @Mahsum: xpath would be just fine.

Comment: Which language? Java or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty easy to get the value you javascript using jQuery.

```
    var text = $(".myAttribute")
    .clone()    
    .children() 
    .remove()   
    .end()  
    .text();

    console.log('text = ' + text);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong way but you can do by this way also.

```
$(".myAttribute").text().split(" ")[$(".myAttribute").text().split(" ").length -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java:
           driver.findElement(by.xpath('//span[@class="myAttribute"]')).getText();